# Liferay: Permission checking in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, liferay

I'm following the Security and Permission chapter of Liferay at http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4 and have reached the **Adding Permission** part.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm using JSF instead of JSP. How do I expose the permission interface to a user using the tags:

```
<liferay-security:permissionsURL modelResource="<%= BlogsEntry.class.getName() %>" modelResourceDescription="<%= entry.getTitle() %>" resourcePrimKey="<%= entry.getPrimaryKey().toString() %>" var="entryURL" />
```

and

```
<liferay-ui:icon image="permissions" url="<%= entryURL %>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`portal:permissionsURL`](https://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/portal-showcase/-/portal-tag/portal/permissionsurl/general):

```
<portal:permissionsURL resourcePrimKey="#{permissionsURLModelBean.portletResourcePrimaryKey}" var="permissionsURL" />
<h:outputLink value="#{permissionsURL}">Click Me!</h:outputLink>
```

This component is available from [the Liferay Faces Portal JAR](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:com.liferay.faces.portal):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.faces.portal</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Liferay Faces Portal Jar, wich is an util jar that can be downloaded from https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/download.

Then you can use the  to put the permission link.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view 
    ...
    xmlns:liferay-security="http://liferay.com/faces/security"
    >
    ...
    <liferay-security:permissionsURL
        modelResource="..."
        modelResourceDescription="..."
        resourcePrimKey="..." >
                permission
    </liferay-security:permissionsURL>  
    ...
</f:view>
```